# How to create Python egg file

Tags: python, packaging, egg

I have questions about egg files in Python.

I have much Python code organized by package and I'm trying to create egg files.
I'm following [instructions](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs#building-eggs), but they are very common.

According to that, it seems I need to have a setup.py file.

1. Would you please tell me what I need to put into setup.py file and where it should reside?
2. I suppose it's enough to create setup.py and then start "setup.py bdist_egg" for getting egg file. Could you please confirm?
3. Is it possible to include only .pyc files into egg file?
4. Having .egg file how I can just start the code from it without unpacking like `java -jar <jar file>` does?

Comment: What should I use instead eggs then? Here's my question about eggs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902732/what-is-pastedeploy-and-do-i-need-to-learn-it-if-eggs-in-python-are-considered-g

Comment: @YauhenYakimovich: that link is now a parked spam domain. Maybe worth editing to use https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/wheel_egg/?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You are reading the wrong documentation. You want this: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode

1. Creating setup.py is covered in the distutils documentation in Python's standard library documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html). The main difference (for python eggs) is you `import setup` from `setuptools`, not `distutils`.
2. Yep. That should be right.
3. I don't think so. `pyc` files can be version and platform dependent. You might be able to open the egg (they should just be zip files) and delete `.py` files leaving `.pyc` files, but it wouldn't be recommended.
4. I'm not sure. That might be “Development Mode”. Or are you looking for some “py2exe” or “py2app” mode?

Comment: +1: Never include the .pyc files.  They are totally confusing.  We accidentally copied windows .pyc files onto a linux box and had the most confusing error traceback messages ever.  Because the filenames where the original Windows filenames.  It was terrifying to see those windows filenames on the production server.

Comment: just use pyinstaller

Answer (score 30):

For #4, the closest thing to starting java with a jar file for your app is a new feature in Python 2.6, [executable zip files and directories](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#other-language-changes).

```
python myapp.zip
```

Where myapp.zip is a zip containing a `__main__.py` file which is executed as the script file to be executed. Your package dependencies can also be included in the file:

```
__main__.py
mypackage/__init__.py
mypackage/someliblibfile.py
```

You can also execute an egg, but the incantation is not as nice:

```sh
# Bourn Shell and derivatives (Linux/OSX/Unix)
PYTHONPATH=myapp.egg python -m myapp
```

```
rem Windows 
set PYTHONPATH=myapp.egg
python -m myapp
```

This puts the myapp.egg on the Python path and uses the -m argument to run a module. Your myapp.egg will likely look something like:

```
myapp/__init__.py
myapp/somelibfile.py
```

And python will run `__init__.py` (you should check that `__file__=='__main__'` in your app for command line use).

Egg files are just zip files so you might be able to add `__main__.py` to your egg with a zip tool and make it executable in python 2.6 and run it like `python myapp.egg` instead of the above incantation where the PYTHONPATH environment variable is set.

More information on executable zip files including how to make them directly executable with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) can be found on [Michael Foord's blog post on the subject](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2008_12_06.shtml#e1038).

Comment: Alternatively one can use virtual environment http://guide.python-distribute.org/installation.html#upgrading

Answer (score 13):

I think you should use [python wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/) for distribution instead of egg now.

> Wheels are the new standard of python distribution and are intended to
>   replace eggs. Support is offered in pip >= 1.4 and setuptools >= 0.8.

Comment: You can't import a wheel, as far as I can tell. Sometimes I just want to deploy my script along with an egg to make it more portable.