# How to pack python files and its dependencies in a single executable file?

Tags: python, executable, archive, libraries

I've got a piece of software which consists of several python sources and a couple of c++ libraries. I'd like to pack them in a executable single file, just like java does with .jar files. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sure is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026395/how-to-create-python-egg-file).

Comment: C extensions and .pyc files are not portable between OSes, Python versions therefore usefulness of binary eggs is debatable. Including python binary as in @UncleZeiv's answer solves part of the problem.

Comment: PEX soubda great (nota surge about c++ extensions support) http://pantsbuild.github.io/pex_design.html

Answer (score 10):

You may want to have a look at [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org), [pyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [others](http://www.freehackers.org/Packaging_a_python_program).

Comment: That's like packing the class files, the standard library, and the VM. Doesn't sound quite like is being asked.

Comment: possibly, but he mentions "executable"; he will decide :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use python egg files, they are very similar to java jar files.

http://mrtopf.de/blog/python_zope/a-small-introduction-to-python-eggs/