# What is PasteDeploy and do I need to learn it if Eggs in Python are considered gone?

Tags: python, pyramid, egg, python-3.3

I'm quite new to Python. I've downloaded the Pyramid Framework and have been trying to understand it. It uses many separate tools for its work. For example some `PasteDeploy`. I tried to read [`PasteDeploy`'s manual](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/) but can't understand anything. There is almost no valuable examples and explanation. Just syntax. All I understood is that it uses `.egg` format everywhere. It is based on `.egg` format:

```
[composite:main]
use = egg:Paste#urlmap

[app:home]
use = egg:Paste#static

[app:blogapp]
use = egg:BlogApp
```

At the same time I found that `.egg` format is going to be thrown away from Python's package's future. Here's [the source](http://guide.python-distribute.org/future.html).
And also at the same time the Pyramid is built around `eggs` too. Every component in its `env\Lib\site-packages` is an `egg` component:

```
chameleon-2.11-py3.3.egg
distribute-0.6.31-py3.3.egg
pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg
pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg
... and so on
```

So I don't understand why it uses `.egg` format if it is considered as some sort of "deprecated"? Why it uses `PasteDeploy` that itself uses almost deprecated `.egg` format? Should I learn `PasteDeploy` or there are some more progressive tools out there now but I don't know about them yet? Will `.egg` format be replaced in Pyramid in closest future?

Comment: The page you're linking to is more like thoughts of a single person. The date at the bottom of the page is 2009. It is possible to find a "confirmation" for just about any claim on Internet using this method :)

Answer (score 10):

The egg format is absolutely not deprecated and anywhere that you read that is lying to you. There are a lot of issues with Python packaging, but Pyramid embraces the state of the art.

Your link discusses goals for the future, but you can't deprecate something that does not yet have a replacement. It will be many years before egg support is actually dropped (there are thousands of packages that use it). That document is just discussing the futuristic goals of where things should go, and (ignoring Python 3) the community has a strong sentiment toward backward compatibility so even if new formats come out, eggs will continue to be supported for a long time.

`PasteDeploy` is the package that Pyramid uses for parsing INI files, configuring a WSGI pipeline and configuring a WSGI server.

The documentation for `PasteDeploy` can be a little rough if you don't have something specific in mind that you are trying to find. Pyramid's docs cover the basic INI settings well enough that you *should* be able to live off of that for a while and if you have something you are trying to accomplish that you can't find, ask another question on SO or use the mailing list.

Aside from all of this, `PasteDeploy` is again just used for parsing INI files. Pyramid itself does not actually require the use of an INI in this way, but it's the simplest way to get people off the ground.