# Import pillow without installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am working on a Python project that requires PIL to show images. However, the computers that I am working on often do not allow me to install things, and have a very bare bones python setup. For this reason, most of the modules that I need I simply place in the same directory as my python files.

I tried doing the same with PIL. I downloaded the pillow source, and copied the PIL folder into my project. I was then able to run "import PIL" with no problems. However, when I then tried to run "from PIL import Image" I get the error: "The _Imaging C module is not installed". From other searches I think that installing Pillow properly would fix this problem, however I would like PIL to be more portable, and not require an instillation.

Any ideas would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are having trouble building the `.egg` file for `PIL`, alternatively you could download `Pillow`'s `.egg` file pre-made [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is bundle `PIL` in with the script in `.egg` form. Then, you can import `PIL` directly from the `.egg` instead of having to install it:

[How to create Python egg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026395/how-to-create-python-egg-file)

The basic process is as follows:

How to create egg:

1. Edit `PIL`'s `setup.py` to include `from setuptools import setup` instead of normal setup import
2. Run `python setup.py bdist_egg`
3. Egg will be inside of `dist/`

How to import egg:

Copy `.egg` file to script's directory and import desired modules:

```
import os
import sys

DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(DIR, "./path/to/PIL.egg"))

#You can now import from PIL normally:
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: I tried doing this, using the pillow egg downloaded from PyPi. However, when using your script, I got the following error:

  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python\PIL test\p import.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File pil egg file, line 63, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
  File pil egg file, line 7, in <module>
  File pil egg file, line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.