# AWS Glue jobs failing due: google-auth version 2.0.0.dev0 is installed but google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.24.0 is required by {'google-cloud-core'}

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, google-authenticator

```
SystemExit: error: google-auth 2.0.0.dev0 is installed but google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.24.0 is required by {'google-cloud-core'}
```

This error appears now on AWS Glue Jobs, in my case, jobs using **smart_open**. Did not happen until now and I was already using .eggs on AWS Glue to be able to run smart_open.

There is a new version of google-auth 1.33.0 since 20th of July 2021, those anyone else encountered this error? AWS has to update this error?

Maybe using a .egg file of google-auth 1.33.0 will solve that issue. Refer to these post on how to do an .egg file [How to create Python egg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026395/how-to-create-python-egg-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was already using an egg for my pythonshell jobs.  However I was *not* freezing the version numbers.

setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
  name="my_glue_dependencies",
  install_requires=[
    'google-auth==1.33.1',
    'google-cloud-storage==1.41.1',
    'google-cloud-bigquery==2.22.0'
  ]
)
```

The key to freezing the versions used is to use `==` instead of `>=` for the `install_requires` options.

The docker image [from this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/developing-aws-glue-etl-jobs-locally-using-a-container/) can be used to build the egg.

Build the egg  `$ python setup.py bdist_egg -d ./dist`

[The full article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html) on python glue jobs, and how to Provide Your Own Python Library.